# Return position of row in MYSQL query with where clause

Tags: mysql

Hoping you can help me with the following query.

I have a table called 'scores' which lists the score of a user and the time taken to achieve the score in.

I would like to return a query that tells the user what position they are on the leaderboard.

**Table Overview**

```
    +----+---------+-------+------------+
    | id | user_id | score | time_taken |
    +----+---------+-------+------------+
    |  2 |       8 | 2     | 2          |
    |  3 |       9 | 2     | 3          |
    |  4 |      10 | 0     | 2          |
    |  5 |      11 | 2     | 3          |
    +----+---------+-------+------------+
```

I have the following query which returns the data i need by creating a new row called 'position' on the fly.

However i am struggling to add a where clause to this statement to return the position column for the given user id.

```
SELECT @rank:= 0;
SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank, s.* FROM (
  SELECT user_id, score, time_taken 
    FROM scores 
    ORDER BY 
        score DESC, time_taken ASC
    LIMIT 100
)s
```

**SQL Data**

```
 CREATE TABLE `scores` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_taken` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `answers` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `scores_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`, `user_id`, `score`, `time_taken`, `answers`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
  (2, 8, '2', '2', '[{\"5\":\"17\"},{\"7\":\"26\"},{\"6\":\"21\"},{\"4\":\"16\"}]', '2015-11-04 17:26:46', '2015-11-04 17:26:46'),
  (3, 9, '2', '3', '[{\"7\":\"25\"},{\"4\":\"14\"},{\"5\":\"17\"},{\"6\":\"22\"}]', '2015-11-04 17:28:47', '2015-11-04 17:28:47'),
  (4, 10, '0', '2', '[{\"7\":\"25\"},{\"4\":\"13\"},{\"6\":\"21\"},{\"5\":\"17\"}]', '2015-11-04 17:29:02', '2015-11-04 17:29:02'),
  (5, 11, '2', '3', '[{\"6\":\"22\"},{\"4\":\"13\"},{\"5\":\"18\"},{\"7\":\"25\"}]', '2015-11-04 17:29:17', '2015-11-04 17:29:17');
```

**Output needed**

I would just like to retrieve the user_id and the position they are within the leaderboard (which is determined by all results, ordered by score, ordered by time taken).

```
+----------+---------+
| position | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|  3       |       9 |
+----------+---------+
```

I've had a look around but can't seem to find a suitable answer that exists.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected result?

Comment: Hey @KostasMitsarakis sure.

I would just like to retrieve the user_id and the position they are within the leaderboard (which is determined by all results, ordered by score, ordered by time taken). I've updated the question with example output.

Comment: wrap it as a subquery then just add a where clause with the user_id and the position you want;

Comment: Hm, why the position of user_id = 8 is 2 and not 1 (there aren't any other rows before this user_id)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to do that other sub:

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
        @i:=@i+1 AS position, 
        t.*
        FROM 
        scores AS t
        ORDER BY score DESC, time_taken ASC
) positions 
WHERE positions.position = 5
```

Or you could just do a limit with an offset.

```
    SELECT 
        t.*
        FROM 
        scores AS t
        ORDER BY score DESC, time_taken ASC
        LIMIT 8, 1
```

Will return the person in position 8.

Comment: you should consider using a HAVING

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02850/2)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS position, aa.id, aa.user_id, aa.score, aa.time_taken
FROM scores AS aa
WHERE aa.id <= (
    SELECT id
    FROM scores
    WHERE user_id = 8
);
```

Result:

```
position    id  user_id score   time_taken  
1           2   8      2        2
```

Comment: The problem with this query is i need to first list the data in order of score DESC, time_taken ASC and add a position to each result. Once i have calculated this i then need to query to find the user id. 

I've updated the query on the description with a query that returns the data set needed. I now need to filter this down to return the position for a selected user id. However when i add a where clause i keep loosing the position value or it returns 1 when it shouldn't.

Comment: Oh, you had to write down this info at the first place.. I had understood something else.

Answer (score 0):

Using the feedback here i have achieved the result i was looking for with the following query which nests subqueries.

```
SELECT @rank:= 0;
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank, s.* FROM (
      SELECT user_id, score, time_taken 
      FROM scores 
      ORDER BY 
      score DESC, time_taken ASC
      LIMIT 100
    )s
)a
WHERE a.user_id = x
```